# Concatenated string as object index

Tags: typescript

I have checked many questions on stackoverflow, but was not able to find a match to my problem, so this question. Please feel free to send a link to a similar question if you find any.

## Problem:

I am trying to access an object's value by using a concatenated index and I get this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'myInterface'

Something like this:

```
myObj[`${key}AB`]
```

## Problem reproduced on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-it0th?file=/src/index.ts

## My code:

```
type PredefinedKey = "test" | "foo" | "bar";

interface myInterface {
  testAB: string;
  fooAB: string;
  barAB: string;
  bazAB: string;
}

const myObj: myInterface = {
  testAB: "something1AB",
  fooAB: "something2AB",
  barAB: "something3AB",
  bazAB: "something4AB"
};

const myFunc = (key: PredefinedKey) => {
  if (myObj[`${key}AB`]) { // <<<----- error on this line
    console.log("Hello world");
  }
};

myFunc("test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**First**, make computed string `${key}AB` a constant value:

```js
type PredefinedKey = "test" | "foo" | "bar";

interface myInterface {
  testAB: string;
  fooAB: string;
  barAB: string;
  bazAB: string;
}

const myObj: myInterface = {
  testAB: "something1AB",
  fooAB: "something2AB",
  barAB: "something3AB",
  bazAB: "something4AB"
};

const myFunc = (key: PredefinedKey) => {
  const x = `${key}AB` as const

  if (myObj[x]) { // ok
    const y = myObj[x] // string
    console.log("Hello world");
  }
};

myFunc("test");
```

`y` variable infers to string.

**Second option**, use `myObj` as a constant value.

```js
type PredefinedKey = "test" | "foo" | "bar";

interface myInterface {
  testAB: string;
  fooAB: string;
  barAB: string;
  bazAB: string;
}

const myObj = {
  testAB: "something1AB",
  fooAB: "something2AB",
  barAB: "something3AB",
  bazAB: "something4AB"
} as const;

const myFunc = <Obj extends myInterface, Key extends PredefinedKey>(obj: Obj, key: Key) => {
  const x = `${key}AB` as const // "testAB" | "fooAB" | "barAB"

  if (obj[x]) { // ok
    const y = myObj[x] // "something1AB" | "something2AB" | "something3AB"
    console.log("Hello world");
  }
};

myFunc(myObj, "test");
```

Comment: Thank you captain. First solution works like a charm. I just want to understand the concept. Why as const works? Can you please explain? I never had an idea that something like this also exists in typescript.

Comment: `as const` means that this value will never mutate and TS can infer the literal type which will be the same as value. I believe it is better to read about it in docs and just play with it in ts playground.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `keyof`

```
type PredefinedKey = "test" | "foo" | "bar";

interface myInterface {
  testAB: string;
  fooAB: string;
  barAB: string;
  bazAB: string;
}

const myObj: myInterface = {
  testAB: "something1AB",
  fooAB: "something2AB",
  barAB: "something3AB",
  bazAB: "something4AB"
};

const myFunc = (key: PredefinedKey) => {
  if (myObj[`${key}AB` as keyof myInterface]) {
    console.log("Hello world");
  }
};

myFunc("test");
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-2o7le?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a possible solution. I am using such key concatenated indexes many times inside my function. So, I think I would keep this solution as last life saving option.